# React/Node app fails to recognize new local image file

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm trying to add a png image as an  tag link that navigates to a facebook page.  I have the png stored locally, but it kicks back the following error:

`Proxy error: Could not proxy request /Media/Images/fb.png from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3400/.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).`

The link syntax is as follows:

`<a href='https://www.facebook.com/foo-bar/' className='facebook'><img src='./Media/Images/fb.png' alt="facebook"/></a>`

I looked for a typo but couldn't find any, I also tried giving the  tag a closing tag rather than keeping it as self-closing, but that did nothing.  Lastly I tried 'requiring' the image as follows:

`<a href='https://www.facebook.com/foo-bar/' className='facebook'><img src={require('./Media/Images/fb.png')}></img></a>`

When I required the image I got the following error:

`Module not found: Can't resolve './Media/Images/fb.png' in 'C:\Users\Administrator\documents\documents\newer-cmp\foo-bar\src'`

My suspicion is that the 'require' syntax is correct, but for some reason it cannot see the png file.  I have no idea why it wouldn't be able to see it, as it has no trouble accessing the other images.  Any direction would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the file matches *exactly* which would include casing of file and extension.  For example if the file on disk is `FB.png` but you're attempting to access it as `fb.png`, depending on your server, it will not find a match.

***DISCLAIMER*** - Aaron asked me to look at it and gave me access to his code-base.

The source at the time I saw did not match the question he asked but instead had the following line: `<a href='https://www.facebook.com/foo-bar/' className='facebook'><img src={require('./Media/Images/fb-white')}></img></a>`.  The file in his source was `fb-white.png`.  I corrected his reference to include the file extension and now it works.